# How to implement Single Sign On using Oauth for colleges

Tags: authentication, oauth, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

So i've spent all morning researching this question to no avail. I am working on a project intended for college students and I want them to use their college credentials to login. According to my colleges website, they use Shibboleth (not really clear what that is).

http://wp.stolaf.edu/it/shibboleth/

But, when I try to sign in, I am redirected to a Google login (maybe because my schools has a google apps account?).

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/identifier?hd=stolaf.edu&client_id=368607578799-f5geh8k6l3km5et1ufbtusikso5sb7rj.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=f79665226a2f8fc&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stolaf.edu&approval_state=!ChRBaTZRcUVWbmJmdWJzRlI3NGo5dxIfOHlPc3B4bTVzTllka0RpS1ROWXNjODdHdXNtRnlSVQ%E2%88%99ADiIGyEAAAAAWT7Z2W-jxans2dR2UJEqLGqZlFcz8o0M&passive=1209600&oauth=1&sarp=1&xsrfsig=AHgIfE-QG4f6y_Kx_8a0952JQ73sLp5JpQ&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

I am confused how Shibboleth and Google are mixed in this scenario. How do I go about authenticating my users against their school credentials in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should first understand what is oauth2 and SAML web SSO. The link of to Google is base on the oauth2 protocol and let third party website (like your college website) to use the user information. So that means Google has the credential of users. If you want to implement the SSO and use your college credentials, that means college is the IdP, not Google. So for SSO, you need neglect the Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the organization appears to support federation via Shibboleth, you should ignore the Google component which you are seeing.

You will need to firstly support SAML 2.0 (most likely) and have your project act as a Service Provider. Shibboleth will produce a signed SAML assertion which will contain identifiable user information that you can validate. When validation has occurred you can then establish a session on your application as the identified user.

To get to that point you will need to work with the college to exchange something called metadata, which determines how your messages should look like. It's unlikely you will be able to get this going without someone from the college working with you.